# How hide the TitleBar or ActionBar after the content is created?

Tags: android

I have a layout where when the keybpard appears I need to hide many elements, including the titlebar.

How can I hide the titlebar after the window/content was created?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a theme to the `Activity` definition in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

If you just want to get rid of the titlebar, use

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`

instead of Fullscreen.